# How do I get the name of a file that I receive in "open in" on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have registered my application to listen for pdfs in "Open In" on iOS, and I get the URL of the file but I dont know how to get the name and mime type.

```
- (void)handleDocumentOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSData *fileContent = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    //would like to get the name

    //would like to get the mimetype
```

A link to documentation or an example would be greatly appreciated. Was not able to find anything about this online (maybe not possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
// Getting the filename:
NSString *fname = [url.path lastPathComponent];

// Getting MIME-type
CFStringRef ext = (CFStringRef)[url.path pathExtension];
CFStringRef uti = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, ext, NULL);
CFRelease(pathExtension);
CFStringRef mime = UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass(uti, kUTTagClassMIMEType);
CFRelease(uti);
```

Don't forget to `CFRelease()` the MIME-type (`mime` variable) when you're done with it.